# How to add event handler to route displayed event in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, fancybox

I have a simple site in Ember.js that has this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('main', { path: '/main' });
    this.route('sub', { path: '/sub' });
```

And template like this:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main/sub">
      <a href='image.jpg' class='fancyBox'><img src='image.jpg'></a>
  </script>
```

Now in order to make FancyBox so that when i click on the image it opens in new layer i normally call function:

```
$("a.fancyBox").fancybox();
```

Now i need to call it when main/sub is displayed. And this must be done after the template main/sub is displayed.

So how to bind event to template being displayed in order to call fancybox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible way to do it would be by creating a `MainSubView` and hook into the [`didInsertElement`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement) function:

```
App.MainSubView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $("a.fancyBox").fancybox();
  }
});
```

The [`didInsertElement`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement) function will be called when the view was inserted into the DOM.

Also worth mentioning is that if the call to `fancybox()` needs some clearing up after the view was removed from the DOM you would do this in [`didInsertElement`'s](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement) counterpart hook [`willDestroyElement`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_willDestroyElement).

Example:

```
App.MainSubView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $("a.fancyBox").fancybox();
  },
  willDestroyElement: function() {
    // remove here the displayed fancybox
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.